# Раскрытие подменю при переходе на определенный раздел Joomla

Tags: joomla

Как настроить в Joomla меню, подпункты которого раскрываются только при переходе на определенный раздел?

Answer (score 0):

Cоздаем два модуля меню, ссылающиеся на одно многоуровневое меню.

В первом ставим показ уровней с 1 по 1 и публикуем на главной позиции, где должно быть основное меню сайта.

В втором модуле ставим уровень подпунктов с 1 по 2 и публикуем его на нужной позиции и нужных страницах